# Add item to parent item within a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi dimensional array, something like this:

```php
$items = array(
    'one' => array(
        'a' => array(),
        'b' => array(),
        'c' => array()
    ),
    'two' => array(
        'd' => array(),
        'e' => array(),
        'f' => array()
    ),
    'three' => array(
        'g' => array(),
        'h' => array(),
        'i' => array()
    )
);
```

So, I could add another array within the tree structure as:

```
$items['one']['c'][] = array( 'j' => array() );
```

But if I don't know that `c` is within `one`, how can I achieve this? I've looked at `array_search` but that just returns `false`. I think that is because what I'm looking for isn't at the top level of the array perhaps?

I know that `c` exists, but I don't know which sub-array it's in and how far down it goes. Is this possible?

Comment: depends on the use case, but I guess `array_search` in combination with `array_keys` could be a sollution

Comment: array_search won't work because c is a key not the a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this function will do what you want:

```
<?php

$items = array(
    'one' => array(
        'a' => array(),
        'b' => array(),
        'c' => array()
    ),
    'two' => array(
        'd' => array(),
        'e' => array(),
        'f' => array()
    ),
    'three' => array(
        'g' => array(),
        'h' => array(),
        'i' => array()
    )
);

function addToSub($items, $key, $addItem) {
   foreach($items as &$item) {
       if (in_array($key, array_keys($item))) {
           $item[$key][] = $addItem;
       }
   }
    return $items;
}

$items = addToSub($items, 'c', array( 'j' => array() ));

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($items);
echo "</pre>";
```

output:

```
array(3) {
  ["one"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["a"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["b"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["c"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["j"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are implementing a tree.
Your first thing to do is to find the node to append a child.
(In your example, the node is c and the child is j)

Implementing DFS search by recursion, I wrote following code.
(Make sure the node you're searching exists, or the function will return empty array)

```
<?php

$arr = [
    'one' => [
        'a' => [],
        'b' => [],
        'c' => [],
    ],
    'two' => [
        'd' => [],
        'e' => [],
        'f' => [],
    ],
    'three' => [
        'g' => [],
        'h' => [],
        'i' => [],
    ],
];

$arr = insertArr($arr, 'c', 'j');

print_r($arr);

function insertArr(array $arr, string $key, string $new): array {
    // If key is found in $arr, append the child and return it.
    if (array_key_exists($key, $arr)) {
        $arr[$key][$new] = [];
        return $arr;
    }

    // search the key in child node(next dimention)
    foreach ($arr as $subArrKey => $subArr) {
        // result will be empty if the key is not in child $subArr
        $result = insertArr($subArr, $key, $new);
        if (!empty($result)) {
            // If the key is found in $subArr, 
            // replace $subArr with $result, 
            // which is the same as the $subArr but appended with child.
            $arr[$subArrKey] = $result;
            return $arr;
        }
    }

    return [];
}
```

Now, you can append 'k' to either 'one', 'c' or 'j'.
To append 'k' to 'j', simply write:

```
$arr = insertArr($arr, 'j', 'k');
```

Answer (score 0):

[array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) will look for a value and in your example all your sub arrays are empty.

If I am not mistaken you could use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and for each subarray check if the key exists that you are looking for with [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
$result = array_map(function($item) {
    if (array_key_exists("c", $item)) {
        $item["c"]["j"] = [];
    }
    return $item;
}, $items);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/PdkOA)